# UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I understood before that
**`Delegate`** pattern is used only for invoking events to `delegate instance` and getting controls (like size / font / etc...).

**`Datasource`** pattern is only for getting data from `datasource instance` (like views / title / description / etc...)

But seems it was a nice illusion, after looking to Apple's `UITableViewDelegate protocol` I got confused because

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Are delegate methods (but I was thinking that they are `UITableViewDatasource` methods)

Is this a dirty code from Apple, or I'm missing something important too understand difference between datasource and delegate?

**EDIT:**
Thanks @DBD for nice answer,
here is more confusion

Here is ***UITableViewDelegate*** method that returns View for drawing

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

And also there is a configuration in ***UITableViewDataSource***

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

And oops, we can see a method that returns a View in ***UITableViewDataSource***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Here we have question why `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `viewForHeaderInSection:` are not in ***UITableViewDataSource***

Comment: They are not data source methods, as they do not provide any data to the table view. They simply determine the height of the row/header/footer.

Comment: @Nick but the data is transferred from delegate to tableView?

Comment: @IOgg3r data come the data source not from the delegate. However, very often we let the data source and delegate be the same object, often it is the table view controller.

Comment: One could argue it should have been implemented the other way, but it wasn't.  Hardly matters, though, since about 95% of the time the same class is used to implement both delegates.

Comment: Data is the content of the cells; the height, etc is part of the appearance of the cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I've always thought about it.

`UITableViewDataSource` to be primary data. What are the actual contents of the table. How many rows? What is the content of row X?

`UITableViewDelegate` was secondary and display data. How tall should it be, should it display in the selected state, and call backs for "hey I'm about to do something."

However I admit I see some of it as a fine line (and I don't buy some of the choices)

`UITableViewDataSource` has `titleForHeaderInSection`.
`UITableViewDelegate` has `viewForHeaderInSection`.

So if it's pure "data" title, it's the data source, but if includes a display wrapper with a view, it's the delegate. But wait, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a view and that's part of the data source, so why would you put `viewForHeaderInSection` in the delegate? While I can barely see the distinction between as "cell" as data and "title view" as delegate, I think the confusion of splitting "title" methods into different protocols is not preferable. I'm sure many might disagree with me, but it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the critical distinction here arises from what you consider "data." From your question, I think you understand "data" to mean "any return value" – that is, methods which return `void` are delegate methods, and methods which return non-`void` are data source methods (since they pass something back to the sending table view).

This can sometimes be a useful approximation, but here is inaccurate. A table view's data is the *contents* that it displays – the stuff in the cells, the titles of sections, etc. Any other information, including that about layout (like row height) or display (like section headers) properly belongs in the delegate, since it is not about the contents of the table – merely about how to display those contents.

The two are very often related, which is why more often than not the same UITableViewController subclass implements both the delegate and data source, but imagine: you could have one object act as the data source and vend cells, then have a different object act as the delegate and provide heights for your rows based on completely different criteria. (Imagine a table where the user can resize rows, for example. You still provide the contents of each row, but the height – the delegate's responsibility – is drawing from a very different set of information.)

Comment: Shouldn't header's view be treated as content as well? If there is a simple situation where header owns only a text label current solution works well - datasource provides title and delegate provides view. But I think that mostly section's header may own more that just a title label and after this small change we have to move all data providing logic to "viewForHeader" method. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

`dataSource` and `delegate` are both protocols but they are separated into two terms so that we can better understand what the methods are designed to do.

**This means:**

1. The `dataSource` protocol defines an API that supplies the data where `delegate` supplies the behavior.
2. `dataSource` is in the model layer and the delegate is in the control layer.

I think this is the correct outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same confusion with you, until I see the Apple's document.

> The UITableViewDataSource protocol is adopted by an object that
>   mediates the application’s data model for a UITableView object. The
>   data source provides the table-view object with the information it
>   needs to construct and modify a table view.
>
> As a representative of the data model, **the data source supplies
>   minimal information about the table view’s appearance**. The table-view
>   object’s delegate—an object adopting the UITableViewDelegate
>   protocol—provides that information.

[UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your point.

The datasource protocol methods are all related to the data. The delegate protocol instead has methods regarding the appearance of the cells.